# how to make PyCharm use the pdm download package

Tags: python, pycharm, pdm

I am using the pdm https://github.com/pdm-project/pdm to manage the python project dependencies, today I found the PyCharm seems did not use the pdm downloaded packages, seems use it's own downloaded package. Is it possible to make the PyCharm use the pdm downloaded package? or Am I missing something?

the pdm already update the package to 0.1.34, but the PyCharm still use the legacy 0.1.29 package. Even through the pdm download the package, the PyCharm still need to redownload the same package. This is the pdm info:

```
> pdm info
PDM version:
  2.10.4
Python Interpreter:
  /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/dolphin/visa/.venv/bin/python (3.10)
Project Root:
  /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/dolphin/visa
Local Packages:
```

this is the pdm environment info:

```
> pdm info --env
{
  "implementation_name": "cpython",
  "implementation_version": "3.10.11",
  "os_name": "posix",
  "platform_machine": "arm64",
  "platform_release": "22.4.0",
  "platform_system": "Darwin",
  "platform_version": "Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 20:59:28 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000",
  "python_full_version": "3.10.11",
  "platform_python_implementation": "CPython",
  "python_version": "3.10",
  "sys_platform": "darwin"
}
```

and the PyCharm version is:

```
PyCharm 2023.2.5 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-232.10227.11, built on November 14, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.9+7-b1000.46 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 10
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.experimental.ui=true
```

Comment: I usually start projects by manually invoking pdm, nox, tox, etc, to create the virtual environment for me. Then afterwards I open PyCharm, and set the interpreter settings use that venv python executable. This is nice because it works with any venv setup tooling.